# Unable to send mail from gmail with xampp (using php script)

Tags: php, email, windows-7, xampp, sendmail.exe

I am using XAMPP on windows 7 but I'm unable to send mail using php

The php.ini file part is as under:

```
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_from = hima***ivast***@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
mail.add_x_header = Off
```

The sendmail.ini file part is as under:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=25
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=hima***ivast***@gmail.com
auth_password=************
force_sender=hima***ivast***@gmail.com
```

Please help me find the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSL enabled on the Gmail account, port number is 587. I believe the other is 465, as per the help docs: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en

> If you tried configuring your SMTP server on port 465 (with SSL) and
>   port 587 (with TLS), but are still having trouble sending mail, try
>   configuring your SMTP to use port 25 (with SSL).

You should probably also be using a try/catch block - if sendmail is failing with an error, you can print_r or var_dump to see what the exception message contains.

I should admit I haven't ever used sendmail directly; I found the Rmail library a lot easier to use:

```
<?php
    require_once( ROOT . DS . "libs" . DS . "Rmail" . DS . "Rmail.php" );

    // Instantiate a new HTML Mime Mail object
    $mail = new Rmail();

    $mail->setSMTPParams($host = 'smtp.gmail.com', $port = 587, $helo = null, $auth = true, $user = 'gmail address', $pass = 'password');

    // Set the From and Reply-To headers
    $mail->setFrom( "Proper Name <send from email address>" );
    $mail->setReturnPath( "reply email address" );

    // Set the Subject
    $mail->setSubject( 'Email subject/title' );

    $html = 'you email message content';

    // Create the HTML e-mail
    $mail->setHTML( $html );

    // Send the e-mail
    $result = $mail->send( array( 'target email address' ) );
?>
```

I can track down the library somewhere if you'd rather use something like the snippet above.

Comment: All the three ports are giving the same result.

Comment: Have you verified that you can log in with the credentials you're using?

Comment: Yes I can log in with the credentials. Is there some error in my code?